# Loading "bower_task.js" tasks...ERROR, Error: EACCES, permission denied .local

Tags: node.js, sails.js, openshift, bower, package.json

Deploying a **SailsJS app** to **Openshift**

## Deploying w/ `git push`

```
remote: ├── express-handlebars@3.0.0 (graceful-fs@4.1.4, glob@6.0.4, object.assign@4.0.3, promise@7.1.1, handlebars@4.0.5)
remote: ├── skipper@0.5.9 (string_decoder@0.10.31, dot-access@1.0.0, async@1.4.2, colors@1.1.2, node-uuid@1.4.7, semver@5.0.3, skipper-disk@0.5.4, debug@2.2.0, multiparty@3.2.10, lodash@2.4.2
remote: ├── sails-util@0.11.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, fs-extra@0.8.1, optimist@0.6.1, underscore.string@2.3.3, switchback@1.1.3)
remote: ├── anchor@0.10.5
remote: ├── reportback@0.1.9 (merge-defaults@0.1.4, switchback@1.1.3, lodash@2.4.2)
remote: ├── grunt-cli@0.1.13 (nopt@1.0.10, resolve@0.3.1, findup-sync@0.1.3)
remote: ├── sails-stringfile@0.3.2 (colors@1.1.2, lodash@2.4.2)
remote: ├── sails-hook-sockets@0.13.7 (uid2@0.0.3, semver@4.3.6, socket.io-client@1.4.6, socket.io@1.4.6, machinepack-urls@3.1.1)
remote: └── waterline@0.11.2 (deep-diff@0.3.3, waterline-schema@0.2.0, async@1.5.2, bluebird@3.2.1, switchback@2.0.0, anchor@0.11.2, waterline-criteria@0.11.2)
remote: npm info ok 
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is bf24b845
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Loading "bower_task.js" tasks...ERROR
remote: >> Error: EACCES, permission denied '/var/lib/openshift/574f48527628e1bce8000273/.local'
remote: Warning: Task "bower:install" not found. Use --force to continue.
remote: 
remote: Aborted due to warnings.
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 574f48527628e1bce8000273 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/574f48527628e1bce8000273/nodejs
remote: #<IO:0x0000000069e290>
remote: #<IO:0x0000000069e218>
remote: )
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed
To ssh://574f48527628e1bce8000273@myapp.rhcloud.com/~/git/webrtc.git
   df77e95..dc8b186  HEAD -> master
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

## UPDATE

Add action hooks. Suggested in [this thread](https://github.com/dbashford/mimosa-bower/issues/29)

```
cd .openshift/action_hooks
```

I have added the code to my existing action hook `pre_start_nodejs`

```
#!/bin/bash
export NODE_ENV=production

if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_DIR/node_modules/bower ]
then
    cd $OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_DIR
    npm install bower
fi

cd $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/repo
HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR bower install
cd $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR

if [ -f "${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}"/Gruntfile.js ]; then
    (cd "${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}"; node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt prod)
fi
```

This helped me to move forward, but I am still stuck with `Error: EACCES, permission denied` to `.local`

## UPDATE 2

In `package.json`, added

```
"build": "HOME=$HOME/app-root/runtime bower install --config.interactive=false && grunt build",
```

but didn't help either

## UPDATE 3

```
1 - rhc ssh proyectname
2 - cd nodejs
3 - npm install bower
4 - cd ..
5 - export HOME=$HOME/app-root/runtime/repo
6 - cd app-root/repo
7 - bower install
```

didn't resolved

I am out of ideas.

I understand that `bower` doesn't have access to `.local`, but don't know how to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped cf. [Source](http://www.tamas.io/deploying-a-node-jssocket-io-app-to-openshift/)

```
EACCESS, permission denied '/var/lib/openshift/[instance-id]/.local'
```

The error message means that you don't have the permission to write the home folder.

Added these in `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "export HOME=/var/lib/openshift/574fce8000273/app-root/runtime/repo; ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install",   <======== 
    "debug": "node debug app.js",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
```

and **Bower** completed installation